# Import our site's events rss into the Facebook events on your page

Tags: facebook, events, import, rss

I was wondering if it was possible to import our site's RSS feed of events into the Events tab for our facebook page.

I have seen plenty of apps to go from facebook out to rss, but we want to go the other way.

I'm guessing it's not possible, but figured it's worth asking. How do I go about requesting a feature like this?
Cheers

Comment: You mean that you want to create the events (coming from your server) to your page? - if yes, that's possible, yes!

Comment: This is no longer possible with graph api v2.0. I hope a new solution becomes available soon.